# Getting issue when retrieving data from sqlite __NSArrayI, NSArrayM using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sqlite, nsarray

I am retrieving data from sqlite using objective-c.
I have run following query:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT encrypted_data FROM show_data WHERE encrypted_data LIKE '%%%@%%'", barCodeID];
    self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"shows.sql"];
    NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];
```

From the above query, i am getting following result from sqlite:

```
<__NSArrayI 0x12819c4f0>(
<__NSArrayM 0x1281921c0>(
(
    A1107008SD,
    "Name Heath",
    Cccll,
    "Address",
    "",
    xx,
    xxxxx,
    xxx,
    "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
    "xxx@xxxx.org",
    "
"
)
)

)
```

I am getting correct result, but it become very difficult to me retrieve data from this type of array.. I want to get A1107008SD, Name Heath value's from array but no idea..

Can any one tell me.. how can i make it simple array.. or how can i get these value's.

I would be very thankful to all of us..

Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple array of arrays.

So, the first row is:

```
NSArray *row = results[0];
```

The first element in the first row is:

```
NSString *string = row[0];
```

If you want third column of 12th row:

```
NSString *string = results[11][2];
```

Etc.